# Connecting to mySQL Database with Java

Tags: java, mysql

In my program I am trying to connect to a mySQL database. This program is written in Java.

I am trying to connect to my database with this code here (*?* is a place holder b/c I dont know what does there.)

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:*?*");
```

I need someone to help me replace the *?* to connect to my database. I know the IP (Just call it `***.***.***` for security reasons, the port which is 3306 and the database is called devicede_Test).

Please help me replace the *?* with the correct string with the info above, thanks!

Comment: probably sth like this: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname`

Comment: Did you notice, that your connection string contains `sqlite`, not `mysql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://***.***.***:3306/dbname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "");
```

Comment: No because it is not a localhost, it is on my webserver hosted by SiteGround

Comment: Dude… to change the IP / host name is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLIte` is not the right driver here. Use:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://**.***.***.***/devicede_Test", user, pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
[?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
```

Here is a sample connection URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
```

Source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html